# If $C$ is a compact set and $(a,b)$ is any open interval, then $C\setminus (a,b)$ is a compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, compactness

Is this proof fine or does it lack rigor? Please help me spot mistakes or improve on it. Thanks!

Proof Attempt:
Let $C$ be compact, so it must be closed and bounded due to the Heine-Borel Theorem. Consider the open interval $(a,b)$ and, w.l.o.g., suppose that $C\cap(a,b)=[a,x]$. Then $(a,x]\nsubseteq C\setminus (a,b)$, but $a\in C\setminus (a,b)$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $C\setminus (a,b)$ is not closed, then $C\setminus (a,b)$ does not contain all its points of closure; that is $\exists$ a point $p$ of $C\setminus (a,b)$ such that $\in(a,x]$, then $a<p\leq x$ which implies $\exists\delta>0$ such that $(p-\delta, p+\delta)\cap C\setminus (a,b)=\emptyset$. So $\forall y\in(a,x]$, $y$ cannot be a point of closure of $C\setminus (a,b)$ ~ a contradiction.

**EDIT**

Attempt(Direct Approach): Let $U$ be an open cover of $C\setminus (a,b)$ such that $C$ is closed and bounded. Since $U\cup\{(a,b)\}$ is an open cover of $C$. But, $C$ is compact so $U\cup\{(a,b)\}$ has a finite subcover. Knowing that $\{(a,b)\}$ does not cover $C\setminus (a,b)$ then $U$ must be finite.

Comment: Why can we suppose that $C\cap(a,b)$ is an interval? What if, say, $C=\left\{\frac1n\,\middle|\,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$?

Comment: I was thinking of considering a compact set $C$ such that $C\setminus (a,b)$ is not empty

Comment: What has that to do with what I wrote? With my $C$, $C\cap(a,b)$ may well be non-empty.

Comment: No, $C\setminus (a,b)$ is not empty and $C\cap (a,b)$ is also not empty.

Comment: With my $C$, both $C\setminus(0,1)$ and $C\cap(0,1)$ are non-empty.

Comment: Don't use Heine-Borel. The definition of $C\setminus(a,b)$ makes it perfectly suited for a direct argument with open covers

Comment: I know your question was about checking your proof, but I think it's worth mentioning that there is a one line proof: $C\setminus (a,b)$ is a closed subset of a compact set ($C$) and hence compact itself.

Comment: @Hayden: That is what I saw immediately after seeing the problem, but I am having difficulty showing $C\setminus (a,b)$ is closed.

Comment: Closed subset of a compact set is compact. Try proving it

Comment: @Adam:I already know how to do that. But where do I apply that? Thanks.

Comment: $C$ is closed (because it's compact). $C\setminus (a, b)$ is closed, it's intersection of $(a, b)^c$ and $C$, two closed sets. Now, we have a closed subset $C\setminus (a, b)$ of $C$, a compact set. So $C\setminus (a, b)$ is compact

Comment: @TheLastCipher As Adam's argument shows, in general removing an open set $U$ from a closed set $F$ gives a closed set, as $F \setminus U = F \cap U^\mathsf{c}$ is an intersection of closed sets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that $C\cap (a,b)$ is a closed interval. That is not at all the case. For instance, what if $C=\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}$ for some $n$? Or $C=\{0,\frac11, \frac12,\frac13,\ldots\}$? Or the Cantor set? As you can see, it doesn't even have to be a *union* of closed intervals in any nice way. As a general intuition, open sets look "nice", but closed sets can be quite "ugly".

However, if $C$ is closed and bounded, what can you say about $C\setminus (a,b)$? Is it closed? Is it bounded?

You can do it a lot more directly from the definition of compact as well. Let $\mathcal U$ be an open cover of $C\setminus (a,b)$. Then $\mathcal U\cup \{(a,b)\}$ is an open cover of $C$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: +1 Started typing then saw your answer. Lol.

Comment: I want to say that $C\setminus (a,b)$ is closed before I've written this proof attempt. But was unsure how to show.

Comment: @TheLastCipher It's easier to show that $\Bbb R\setminus (C\setminus(a,b))$ is open, using that $(a,b)$ and $\Bbb R\setminus C$ are both open.

Comment: I'll also give the direct approach a try. I'll comment if I have any more problems. Thank you.

Comment: To the proposer: The point of the last paragraph of this Answer is that if $ C$ is a compact subset of any space $X$  and if $U$ is an open subset of $X$ then $C$ \ $U$ is compact.

Comment: @Arthur: Just woke up and added in the direct approach. Thanks!